# How to fit the map in a destination point with MapViewDirections on react native?

Tags: react-native, google-maps, directions

How to fit the map in a destination point?
I just need to fit the camera to the destination point, not to both coordinates (initial and destination like today). How do I do this? Another way to fit the coordinates to this?

```jsx
{destination && (
  <Fragment>
    <Directions
      origin={region}
      destination={destination}
      onReady={result => {
        this.setState({ duration: Math.floor(result.duration) });
        this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
          edgePadding: {
            right: getPixelSize(10),
            left: getPixelSize(10),
            top: getPixelSize(10),
            bottom: getPixelSize(50),
          },
          animated: true,
        });
      }}
    />
    <Marker
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
      coordinate={destination}
      centerOffset={{ x: -18, y: -60 }}
      anchor={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
    //opacity={0.6}
    >
      <LocationBox>
        <LocationText>{destination.title}</LocationText>
      </LocationBox>
    </Marker>
    <Marker
      coordinate={region}
      anchor={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
      onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}>
      <LocationBox>
        <LocationTimeBox>
          <LocationTimeText>{duration}</LocationTimeText>
          <LocationTimeTextSmall>
            Tempo de Viagem
          </LocationTimeTextSmall>
        </LocationTimeBox>
        <LocationText>{location}</LocationText>
      </LocationBox>
    </Marker>
  </Fragment>
)}
```

It would be nice if anyone has some code that works together with `GooglePlacesAutocomplete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using react-native-maps, you can use these methods:

**animateToRegion**: takes two params:

- `region`, an object with longitude, latitude, longitudeDelta, latitudeDelta (last two are how close/far away your camera will be from the coords)
- `duration`, the animation duration in milliseconds

```
// focus on NYC

this.mapView.animateToRegion({
  latitude: 40.730610,
  longitude: -73.935242,
  latitudeDelta: 0.026,
  longitudeDelta: 0.027,
}, 2000)
```

**fitToCoordinates**: takes two params:

- `coordinates`, an array of coordinates to be fit in the camera view
- `options`: `edgePadding` (how much padding should surround the view), `animated` (whether you want to animate to this view or not)

```
// focus on NYC

this.mapView.animateToRegion([{
  latitude: 40.730610,
  longitude: -73.935242,
}], {
  edgePadding: {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20,
  },
  animated: true,
})
```

These methods need to be called on the ref to the your map, like how you do in your code example: `this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(...)`

There are a bunch of methods that you can use to fit the camera to a destination point, potentially better suited to your use case than what I've described above. Check the [RN Maps docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) for more info.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using the react native maps... I know that is possible to use these two parameters, but how do I will set to the code above just take zoom in the destination point? thank you

Comment: The two methods above allow you to focus on a point or group of points and decide which "zoom level" you want (either with lon/lat Delta, or with edgePadding).
If this doesn't answer your question, please edit your post and give more clarifications. Cheers!

Comment: Hi I used your method, but I have changed the way to search the location, You help me to have an idea, I set your answers right because of this...

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I remove the method directions and replace for this animation one:

Add this method:

```
  getCoordsFromName(loc) { 
     this.mapView.animateToRegion({
      ...this.state.region,
      latitude: loc.lat,
      longitude: loc.lng,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    });
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        region: {
          ...prevState.region,
          latitude: loc.lat,
          longitude: loc.lng,
        },
      };
    });
  }
```

accordingly with:

```
 <MapInput style = {{flex: 1, position : 'absolute'}} notifyChange={loc => this.getCoordsFromName(loc)} />
```